# How to filter a relational datasource of a widget

Tags: google-app-maker

How is it possible to filter a relational datasource of a widget?

I want to filter a relational datasource of a widget by a static and/or diynamic parametres?

[image: Datasources]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no easy way to do it at this time.

However you can emulate desired behavior with multiple datasources. Let's say we have `School` (one) and `Student` (many) models. Given that we can make two queries: one to get the school and other to get students:

```javascript
app.datasources.Schools.query.filters.Id._equals = 1;
app.datasources.Schools.load();

app.datasources.Students.query.filters.School.Id._equals = 1;
app.datasources.Students.query.filters.Age._greaterThen = 20;
app.datasources.Students.load();
```

This approach can also gracefully handle paging for related records. You can find complete code sample in [Project Tracker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/) template (ViewProject page).